# Error: Response is not valid JSON object on firebase function with onCall

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Here is my cloud function code

```
 exports.markThemAllRead = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
    const user = {
        id: data.id,
    }
    let batch = admin.firestore().batch();

    admin.firestore().collection("Notifications").doc("comments").collection(user.id).get().then(querySnapshot => {
        if(querySnapshot.empty){
            return "nice"
        }else {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
                batch.update(doc.ref, {isRead:true})
            });
            return batch.commit()
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
    return "Good"
    })
```

I tried many combinations of return statements, but I keep getting **Error: Response is not valid JSON object**. Can anyone guide me through what could the issue be? I have many other working onCall functions in my code, but this is one is the only one with the batch.update()... perhaps that has something to do with it?

**EDIT ATTEMPT**

Still getting the same error when trying this:

```
exports.markThemAllRead = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
    const user = {
        id: data.id,
    }

    return markThemRead(user)

})

async function markThemRead(user){
    let batch = admin.firestore().batch();

    const docsRef = admin.firestore().collection("Notifications").doc("comments").collection(user.id)

    const docs = await docsRef.get();

    docs.forEach(function(doc){
        batch.update(doc.ref, {isRead:true})
    })

    return batch.commit()

}
```

Comment: Your function needs to return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.  This one tries to return "Good" immediately without waiting for anything.  Also, try returning an object, not a string.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. I edited part of my question with code, is that what you were hinting to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example of in the Firebase documentation [Sync, async and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions#how_promises_work_with_functions)

```
async function markThemRead(user){
    let batch = admin.firestore().batch();

    const docsRef = admin.firestore().collection("Notifications").doc("comments").collection(user.id)

    const docs = await docsRef.get();

    docs.forEach(function(doc){
        await batch.update(doc.ref, {isRead:true})
    })

    return batch.commit().then(function () { return {status: "All Good"}})

}
```